# How can I select all checkboxes from a form using pure JavaScript (without JS frameworks)?

Tags: javascript

I have question, how write function to  select  all  chceckbox  on  form, when  all  checkbox Id start  from  some const.  string,  using  pure java script
(without  jquery  and other frameworks) ?  I know how  do it  using  each function from JQuery, but  I dont  have any idea hwo do it  in pure  JS.My form ex.

```
    <form id="myId" name="myForm">
<input type="checkbox"  id="lang_1" value="de"/> DE
<input type="checkbox"  id="lang_2" value="us"/> US
<input type="checkbox"  id="lang_3" value="ru"/> RU
<input type="button" onclick="Select();"  value="Select all"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case:

```
for (i = 1; i<3; i++) {
  document.getElementById('lang_'+i).checked = true;
}
```

Comment: An element other than checkbox can have a checked attribute. Do consider the solution proposed by James

Comment: Yes, or not have a checked attribute at all, I just replied to the example. James' answer is definitely more thorough.

Answer (score 87):

You could use `getElementsByTagName` to get all the `input` elements:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
        inputs[i].checked = true; 
    }  
}
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Vepx/) of that. If you only care about newer browsers, you could use `querySelectorAll`:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].checked = true;   
}
```

And an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/7F5QR/) of that one. As an aside, you mentioned in your question that when using jQuery you could do this using `each`. You don't need to use `each`, as most jQuery methods operate on all elements in the matched set, so you can do it in just one line:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
```