# Checkbox:checked with Javascript and not JQuery

Tags: javascript

I have problem when I try to mark a checkbox "checked" via Javascript. I am sharing the Fiddle link of it. I want to do it with plain Javascript and not JQuery.

```
[Fiddle link]http://jsfiddle.net/vineetgnair/pne58wyh/
```

Thanks for Help

Comment: Please show the relevant code directly in your question. And describe the problem: does your code result in errors shown in the browser dev console, or does your code do *something* but not the *right* thing, or...?

Comment: what is it that you want to achieve here exactly?

Comment: for(var i=0; i< checkBox.length;i++) { checkBox[i].checked = true;}, i guess this is what you want...

Comment: You should read the  documentation first, it'll tell you why this doesn't work this way.

Comment: Had you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791507/how-can-i-select-all-checkboxes-from-a-form-using-pure-javascript-without-js-fr maybe it can help you mate ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var checkBox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

// querySelectorAll returns an array of the matching elements

function selectAll() {
  for (i = 0; i < checkBox.length; i++) {
    // loop through and set "checked" to TRUE on every element in the checkBox array
    checkBox[i].checked = true;
  }
}

function deselectAll() {
  // loop through and set "checked" to FALSE on every element in the checkBox array
  for (i = 0; i < checkBox.length; i++) {
    checkBox[i].checked = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Select All" onclick="selectAll()">
<input type="button" value="Deselect All" onclick="deselectAll()">
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is pretty much the same except I added a parameter in the selectAll function

```
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Select All" onclick="selectAll(true)">
<input type="button" value="Deselect All" onclick="selectAll(false)">
```

For the javascript, you just needed a loop to set all the items to checked or unchecked

```
function selectAll(selected) {
    var checkBox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

    for(var i = 0 ; i < checkBox.length ; i++) {
        checkBox[i].checked = selected;
    } 
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pne58wyh/1/)