# Checkbox select using querySelectorAll is not working

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have the following code, mostly from [How can I select all checkboxes from a form using pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791507/how-can-i-select-all-checkboxes-from-a-form-using-pure-javascript-without-js-fr) and it's just not working.

**Test.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function select(){
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            inputs[i].checked = true;   
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myId" name="myForm">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1"/> 1
        <input type="checkbox" value="2"/> 2
        <input type="checkbox" value="3"/> 3
        <input type="button" onclick="select()"  value="Select all"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Clicking the button does nothing.
I must be doing something really wrong here but I just can't pick it out.

Comment: Try changing the `onclick` function handler name from `select()` to some different name, not conflicting with known tags...See this.. http://jsfiddle.net/t6b91d6m/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try any other name for function `select`, rest your code is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Try this...

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function test(){
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            inputs[i].checked = true;   
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myId" name="myForm">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1"/> 1
        <input type="checkbox" value="2"/> 2
        <input type="checkbox" value="3"/> 3
        <input type="button" onclick="test()"  value="Select all"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`select` is a native method defined on HTMLInputElement to focus selected input element. 
[select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select)

Solution1: Change the name of your function. 
Solution2: Try `onclick="window.select()"` insted of `onclick="select()"`

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you To use **Jquery** and do like so :

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ywv8x28x/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul class="chk-container">
<li><button id="selecctall">select all</button>
<li><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item1"> This is Item 1</li>
<li><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item2"> This is Item 2</li>
<li><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item3"> This is Item 3</li>
<li><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item4"> This is Item 4</li>
<li><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item5"> This is Item 5</li>
<li><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item6"> This is Item 6</li>
<li><input class="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item6"> Do not select this</li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selecctall').mouseup(function(event) {  //on click 
        if(document.activeElement.tagName ==='BUTTON') { // check select status
            $('.checkbox1').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
            });
        }else{
            $('.checkbox1').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
            });         
        }
    });

});
```

Simpler and more efficient way