# How can I disable all checkboxes on webpage at once?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, input

I have several sets of checkboxes on a webpage.  I want to uncheck them all with javascript.  Right now, I do it by looking for the names of each set and unchecking them with FOR loops like this...

```
    for (i=0;i<document.getElementsByName("myboxes").length;i++) {
document.getElementsByName("myboxes")[i].checked=false;}

for (i=0;i<document.getElementsByName("moreboxes").length;i++) {
document.getElementsByName("moreboxes")[i].checked=false;}

for (i=0;i<document.getElementsByName("evenmoreboxes").length;i++) {
document.getElementsByName("evenmoreboxes")[i].checked=false;}
```

I'm looking for a way to target them all with one loop.  I could do `getElementsByTagName('input')` to target all INPUTS, but that's a problem because I have some radio inputs that I don't want to uncheck.  Is there a way to target all `checkbox inputs`?

---

Thanks for the suggestions.  I just thought of something.  Each NAME I use has the word "boxes" in it, myboxes, moreboxes, evenmoreboxes.  Is there a way to target the word "boxes" in in the name, like a wildcard, something like `document.getElementsByName("*boxes")`  that way if I add a set of checkboxes at some point that I don't want to uncheck I can simply name them differently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select all checkboxes from a form using pure JavaScript (without JS frameworks)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791507/how-can-i-select-all-checkboxes-from-a-form-using-pure-javascript-without-js-fr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all checked checkboxes and reset their state:

```js
function uncheckAll() {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[name$="boxes"]:checked')
    .forEach(checkbox => checkbox.checked = false);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="a_boxes" checked/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="b_boxes" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="c_boxes" checked/>


<button onclick="uncheckAll()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this one best so far.  I just added an update to my question. See above

Answer (score 0):

you can use `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');` to get a list of them all. then run your loop

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[name=myboxes], [name=moreboxes], [name=evenmoreboxes]").forEach((e) => echecked=false);
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[name=myboxes], [name=moreboxes], [name=evenmoreboxes]").forEach((e) => e.checked=false);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="myboxes" value="1" checked>1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="moreboxes" value="2" checked>2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="evenmoreboxes" value="3" checked>3<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @imjared, you can use `querySelectorAll`, but you will have to iterate over it:

```
querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(c => c.checked = false);
```

Here is the [doc for querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)